# Angular Mat Table - Stick a column to the left on selection

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am trying to transform the Angular Material table into a dynamic table. I am using a dialog with checkboxes so I can select columns to display, as you can see:
[image: 1]

Unfortunately, I am having problems with the display of the actions column. I don't like the horrible space I get on the right when this field is selected.
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Here is action ng-container in mat-table:

```
        <!-- actions-->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="edit(row)">
          <mat-icon mat-icon-button color="primary">edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="delete$(row._id)">
          <mat-icon mat-icon-button color="warn">delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button
          mat-icon-button
          color="mat-grey"
          (click)="openInfo(row._id)"
        >
          <mat-icon>more_horiz</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```